# Laptop constantly suspends

Tags: systemd, suspend

I'm having problems with a new Debian 11 laptop which works fine some days, but other days it repeatedly goes to sleep after being up for about 30 seconds.

```
stew@simswe28:~$ sudo systemctl status sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
● sleep.target - Sleep
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/sleep.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Aug 24 08:18:36 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:18:46 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:19:14 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:22:14 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:22:42 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:25:40 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:26:10 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:26:42 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:27:10 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 24 08:27:19 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.

● suspend.target - Suspend
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/suspend.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

Aug 24 08:18:46 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:18:46 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:22:14 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:22:14 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:25:40 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:25:40 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:26:42 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:26:42 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:27:19 simswe28 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 24 08:27:19 simswe28 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.

● hibernate.target - Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hibernate.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)

● hybrid-sleep.target - Hybrid Suspend+Hibernate
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/hybrid-sleep.target; static)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:systemd.special(7)
```

Can I have some ideas for confirming a hardware problem or isolating a configuration problem? What is trying to raise `suspend.target`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the issue with `sudo systemctl mask suspend.target`.  This will stop your machine from constantly suspending.  However the underlying cause is still present.

After getting to a stable state, look around to figure out what's commanding that suspend.  One option could be the power-button is loose.  Confirm that by running [`acpi_listen`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/acpi_listen) from package `acpid`.  If a power-button event is seen, or the laptop lid switch closes, you'll see these types of messages:

```
~$ acpi_listen 
button/power PBTN 00000080 00000000
button/power LNXPWRBN:00 00000080 00000001
button/lid LID open
button/lid LID close
button/lid LID open
```

If it runs for a while with no messages, then that's not your problem.

If you notice any processes are taking a lot of resources, those are worth inspecting.  In my case, my fan was quite loud and noticed `systemd-{logind,journal}` taking up a lot of resources using `top`:

```
    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                                                                                                                     
    724 root      20   0  515012   8348   6880 R  87.5   0.1   7:15.06 systemd-logind                                                                                                                              
    321 root      20   0  482776 306700 304868 S  12.5   1.9   0:55.29 systemd-journal
```

`journalctl -f` will help isolate the cause to those processes.  In my case this was constantly repeating:

```
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Suspending...
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Suspending...
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Suspending...
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Unit suspend.target is masked, refusing operation.
Aug 24 08:44:42 simswe28 systemd-logind[724]: Failed to execute suspend operation: Permission denied
```

In this case, `systemd-logind` is reacting to some signal.  You can isolate and inhibit the signal through `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`.

In my case, I set several options at a time to `ignore`, then `systemctl unmask suspend.target && systemctl restart systemd-logind`.  I found changing `HandleLidSwitch=` from `suspend` to `ignore` solved the problem (even though `acpi_listen` didn't log lid-switch events).

Answer (score 0):

My laptop used to suspend at random, it turned out the battery wasn't charging properly (busted charger cable). Other reasons could be overheating (not enough airflow around the machine).